# How to store values displayed in message box to a different sheet after clicking "ok" on message box

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

Is there any way by which i can store the data which i have displayed in a message box in excel using vba to a new sheet in same workbook one after another like an entry after clicking "ok" on the message box using vba?

this is the code which i have tried as suggested by @MarcinSzaleniec but it is not working -

```
Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)
Dim sMsg As String
sMsg = MsgBox("Values saved in cell " & Replace(Selection.Address, "$", ""))
If MsgBox(sMsg) = vbOK Then ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1") = sMsg

End Sub

Sub Test()

Workbook_AfterSave True

End Sub
```

i want to store the values in other sheet after clicking on "Ok" button like in the below photos-

[image: this is the message box with some details in sheet1 see the picture here]

[image: i want to store the displayed value in sheet2 as shown in picture]

Comment: Could you give an Example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, it is. You must store it first, and then display. 
Let say

```
Dim sMsg as String
sMsg = "Hello"
Workkbooks("MySheet").Range("A1") = sMsg
MsgBox sMsg
```

So, you have then stored your message in the variable and in the worksheet, you can do with it whatever you want.

If you want to print it in the worksheet only after ok is pressed, you may;

```
If MsgBox(sMsg) = vbOK Then Workkbooks("MySheet").Range("A1") = sMsg
```